# How to increase the Write speed of Usb 3.0 flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-3

Currently i am getting the below mentioned *average* speeds while tranferring (Writing) a big video file of 2GB by using **SanDisk ultra Usb 3.0 16 GB** on WIndows 7 64 Bit on Lenovo B590 Laptop :-

Usb3.0 Driver Name :-Intel® USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller Driver
on Usb 2.0 port :- 14MBps
on Usb 3.0 port :- 22MBps
Ram : -2GB DDR3
Processor :- Intel core i3

No Copying tool like **teracopy** or **copyhandler** used 
used Windows Default copying Mechanism
Also getting speed drops From 100Mbps to 22 Mbps on Usb3.0 port

No change occurred even after **Changing the Drive Policy** 

 
Does **Bios** settings need a change?

Is the Windows 7 file copy dialog bugged?

Comment: Which tool did you use to get the results? Or is it the approximate value. What do you mean by speeds? Read or write. Specify

Comment: i copied a single video file in windows 7

Comment: Read from drive or write to file? Also look into [this](http://usbspeed.nirsoft.net/?g=16gb) Will give an idea of average speeds people get

Comment: writing to the drive

Comment: Also share the methods you have tried and where you are stuck. Dont expect people here to do research for you

Comment: “it must be atleast 50Mbps”—why?

Comment: cuz thats wat i have seen here [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCgxgpHMyHs)

Comment: You seem to be using b to represent byte as in 16 Gb. This would normally indicate bits. Capital B is used for bytes. Please confirm that the speeds you are quoting are bytes per second or bits per second.

Answer (score 0):

i found this useful
1.Right click on the Drive
2.Format
3.Choose File System as NTFS
4.choose Allocation unit size as 64KB
5.Start